# Multi thread write to database in c++

Tags: sql-server, database, multithreading

I want to use multithread to write data to MSSQL database in C++. Can I do it?
I think It can deadlocked or we must to wait. But I still want use multithread. Any idea?

Comment: What is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: ex, I have 3 threads to write data to db. My program will stop when they done. And sometimes, It was deadlocked.

Comment: I'm asking you to try yourself first and comeback if you have any problem along with code you tried. We need to see your effort.

Comment: yes, I did. My code is long, so I cannot show it. I want disscuss to slove

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do it?

Can you program or are you willing to learn it? Because the "I" in the question is the critical thing. What you ask for is technically possible - but I have no idea whether you are capable of it.

> I think It can deadlocked or we must to wait.

Generally every multi threaded data access MAY deadlock or wait. Which includes multi machine access - i.e. have hundreds of users accessing one database. Is there a question in there? The approaches to avoid deadlocks are well documented. Wait (i.e. wait for a writable lock) is also well documented.

> But I still want use multithread. Any idea?

Learn enough programming to "just do it". Because this really is it - just do it.